# How to on Facebook wall using Graph API

Tags: facebook

I have developed an application for facebook. I want that whenever any user add my application by clicking on allow permission dialog, a message is automatically posted on the users wall only for the first time.

```
    <?php

include_once 'fb_sdk_212/src/facebook.php';
include_once 'config.php';

$flag_post=0;

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
    'cookie' => true,
    'domain' => 'xxxxx.in'
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if (!$session) {

    $flag_post=1;    

    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
               'canvas' => 1,
               'fbconnect' => 0,
               'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream'
           ));



    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$url';</script>";



} else {

    try {

        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');

        $updated = date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($me['updated_time']));

        echo "Hello " . $me['name'] . "<br />";
        echo "You last updated your profile on " . $updated."<br/>";

        if($flag_post == 1){
        # let's check if the user has granted access to posting in the wall
        $api_call = array(
            'method' => 'users.hasAppPermission',
            'uid' => $uid,
            'ext_perm' => 'publish_stream'
         );

   $can_post = $facebook->api($api_call);
   echo $can_post;
   $attachment = array(
    'name' => 'Tracer',
    'description' => 'xxxx',
    'caption' => 'xxxxx',
    'picture' => 'images/mt75.jpg',
    'link' => 'tracer/'

    );

    if($can_post){
        # post it!

        $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed', 'post', $attachment );
        echo 'posted';
    } else {
        die('Permissions required!');
    }
        }

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

        echo "Error:" . print_r($e, true);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you have to stated what language you gonna use .. rails? php? because different framework or language use different library for it. I use omniauth in rails.

Comment: or you plan to do it from the scratch ...

Comment: i have done it using php sdk.

Comment: the above code is always posting a message on user wall whenever the user visits the application. I want to change it so that only for the first time the application will post message automatically not for every time.

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to get `publish_stream` extended permission.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

This can be done in the permission dialog

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login

by adding `publish_stream` to the `perms` list.

After that you will be able to publish to the user's wall at any time.

Comment: thanks for your sugession bro. I have done that. I want that how will be the algo so that the application post the message automatically on adding it to the profile only for the first time.

Comment: @user429727: you cannot handle that event.

Comment: ya how to handel that .. can you suggest the algo

Comment: @user429727: you cannot. There is no way to catch this event.

Answer (score 1):

I would do one of the following:

1. Add a field in a database table to indicate that it has been done. Then just check if it has been set. If cookies are enabled on the users PC you could use but using a database would be best.
2. Get the user to take an action to do the post. So it requires a user action. This has the disadvantage that some users may not do it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you can handle this fairly easily without Facebook being involved in decision to publish to the users wall or not.  In your database's user table you should have a column for first_fb_post. When a user account is created it should default to 0, then once you publish the wall post it should be updated to 1.

And your facebook publish function would be set like:

```
if($first_fb_post == 0)
 {
    //your FB publishing code here

    //update your user table to mark this users first_fb_post to 1
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the first time the user "installs" your app. When they do this they are redirected to your site with a get parameter of 'code' set in the url:

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    // User Authorized app. Lets hook the install event.
        if($can_post){
            # post it!

            $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed', 'post', $attachment );
            echo 'posted';
        } else {
            die('Permissions required!');
        }
}
```